# Method Replace in Core Plot 1.0 ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, graph, core-plot

I want to used this method in core plot 1.0 but that method now work with core plot 1.0 so what will be alternative for this ?

```
CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
**//this all method are not work**
y.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
y.minorGridLineStyle = minorGridLineStyle;
y.visibleRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(100.0f)];
CPTConstraints yConstraints = {CPTConstraintFixed, CPTConstraintFixed};
y.isFloatingAxis=YES;
y.constraints=yConstraints;
```

i want to try this Example but that give me error [Example link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729366/moving-date-on-x-axis)

Answer (score 0):

The way constraints are handled changed. See the announcement on the [Core Plot discussion board](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/coreplot-discuss/71NaK4N0rTE/discussion).

Here's a summary of the change:

`CPTConstraints` allows two basic types of constraint. Note that when 
used for floating axis positioning, the axis doesn't clip the 
constrained position to the visible area so it is possible to use an 
offset that will push the floating axis outside the visible area.

1. Fixed offset from either the lower or upper bound of the range. 
   Note that for axes, this range is in view coordinates, so the lower 
   bound is to the left for a horizontal axis and at the bottom for a 
   vertical axis. The offset is towards the middle of the range, so a 
   positive offset from the lower bound goes in the positive direction 
   but a positive offset from the upper bound goes in a negative 
   direction.
2. Relative offset. This is used to maintain a position that is a 
   certain fraction of the range—0.0 is the lower bound, 1.0 is the 
   upper bound, and 0.5 is the middle. It is not restricted to these 
   values; any `CGFloat` value can be used.

`CPTConstraints` is immutable, so you have to create a new object 
whenever you want to change the constraints.